# Git: HEAD detached want to push changes

Tags: git

I was working on a local branch and have been pushing my changes up.

I found out I made a mistake and checkout an earlier commit.

I then fixed my errors and want to push my corrections up.

When I do git status I get the following message:

```
C:\dev\ccr>git status
# HEAD detached from d6ddcfa
```

Lets say I am working on branch1.

if I want to push my changes up do I use: 
    git push origin HEAD:branch_name

or:
    git push origin branch1:branch_name

or should I be doing something else?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a new branch starting at your detached `HEAD`.  That is, from your detached `HEAD`, run something like:

```
git checkout -b new_branch_name
```

Now you can start committing changes, and they will be visible on branch `new_branch_name`.  If you then want to merge these into your `master` branch, you can use the `git merge` command:

```
git checkout master
git merge new_branch_name
```

For more information about detached heads:

- http://marklodato.github.io/visual-git-guide/index-en.html#detached
- https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial/git-branches#!checkout

...and there are many (many!) other documents out there that discuss this.

Answer (score 0):

Merging is one option (see larsks' answer), but I'd probably just rebase the new changes on top again. I'd create a branch where I was on the headless branch (`git branch temp`), then rebase it on top of master again (`git rebase master`), fixing any conflicts along the way. Then I'd switch to master (`git checkout master`), and reset it to where the temp branch is (`git reset --hard temp`). Then I'd checkout the master branch (`git checkout master`) and delete the temp branch (`git branch -d temp`).

If this accidentally-created branch was a sensible branch, and not something that should have happened inline with the master branch, then I'd go with larsks' answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all that have responded.

I tried the methods you suggested but I kept getting another error about my branch being behind the origin/master etc2 and it was just spiraling out of control.

This answer is not the most correct or the best it is more for my own record for future reference when I encounter a similar situation.

How I resolved it was I created a new local branch, merged the origin master via:

git checkout -b some_branch origin/master

and I re did all the changes I wanted in this new local branch before pushing up to the remote into a new branch.